# ¿Qué es el strict aliasing?

Tags: c++, c

Tengo entendido que el strict aliasing es una técnica de optimización del compilador y que romper estas reglas puede desencadenar comportamiento indefinido como este:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  char i = 0;
  char j = 0;
  char *p = &i;
  void *q = p;
  int *pp = (int *)q;
  printf("%d %d\n", i, j);
  *pp = -1;
  printf("%d %d\n", i, j);

  return 0;
}
```

¿Por qué este código rompe las reglas de strict aliasing y qué es el strict aliasing?

Comment: ¡Una pregunta muy interesante! Voy a necesitar un poco de investigación para poder responder adecuadamente. Por cierto, el código que presentas es completamente [tag:c] ¿por qué añadiste también la etiqueta [tag:c++]?

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus este tema compete a ambos lenguajes. Creo que es interesante que se quede con ambas etiquetas

Comment: Pues alguien ha quitado la etiqueta [tag:c++].

Comment: @Paula_plus_plus arreglado, puse las dos etiquetas por lo que dijo eferion

Answer (score 1):

Vale, así rápido, el "pointer aliasing" sucede cuando 2 o más punteros apuntan a la misma dirección de memoria. En C y C++ el "strict aliasing" se conoce como las reglas que permiten al compilador asumir, que dos punteros no son alias cuando su tipo es diferente.

Sobre porqué se decide esto, recomiendo leer este excelente artículo (en inglés) que lo explica aún mejor que yo, con ejemplos: https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8 pero lo intentaré resumir un poco:

```
int foo(int *x, int *y) {
  *x = 0;
  *y = 1;
  return *x;
}
```

Ese código claramente debería devolver 0, sin embargo el compilador piensa que tanto x como y pueden apuntar al mismo sitio, y por tanto, el ensamblador que genera es este:

```
foo:    movl    $0, (%rdi)
        movl    $1, (%rsi)
        movl    (%rdi), %eax
        ret
```

Que básicamente, mete un 0 en un registro llamado rdi, un 1 en un registro llamado rsi y sale de la función foo devolviendo rdi. (Lo que se devuelve se guarda en eax)
Esto es un fallo de optimización pues copia un 0 al registro de salida en una función pura como es esta. E aquí cuando es útil el uso de estas reglas:

```
int foo2(int *x, long *y) {
  *x = 0;
  *y = 1;
  return *x;
}
```

Genera:

```
foo2:   movl    $0, (%rdi)
        xorl    %eax, %eax
        movq    $1, (%rsi)
        ret
```

En este caso, tenemos nuestras variables donde tienen que estar, y se hace un xor de eax con eax para devolver siempre 0. El porqué es esto una optimización importante lo puedes ver en este enlace (inglés) https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/12/29/the-surprising-subtleties-of-zeroing-a-register/

Bien, ahora que sabemos qué es strict aliasing, que pasa cuando lo rompemos y porqué lleva a un comportamiento indefinido se puede ver ya a ojo, porque C y C++ permiten hacer casteos de punteros de tipos difernetes, que pueden llegar a producir situaciones que violan las asunciones que hace el compilador. En linea con el ejemplo inmediatamente superior:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long foo(int *x, long *y) {
  *x = 0;
  *y = 1;
  return *x;
}

int main(void) {
  long l;
  printf("%ld\n", foo((int *)&l, &l));
}
```

Ahora si tenemos que los dos parámetros de la función sí apuntan a la misma localización de memoria, pero como son de distinto tipo, el compilador cree que no.

Un apunte final:
Sobre el código que propones ahí el problema que veo que puede suceder es que, accedes como un int (l=4) a un tipo char (l=1) y cuando lo modificas por un -1 (en binario FFFFFF, todo unos) te cargas el i y el j, y al imprimirlo como %d imprimes (FF) que en decimal es -1. Cuando compilas con optimización, el compilador entiende que solo quieres modificar i, y solo cambia el valor de i.

Espero que esto te haya dejado claro en concepto. Un saludo.